# Infinite Series: Is this a valid argument?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, solution-verification

I'm asked to provide a proof for the below:

> Prove that if $\sum a_n$ is a convergent series of non-negative terms,
> then $\sum a_n^2$ converges.

**My Proof/Argument**:
Since $\sum a_n$ is convergent, this means $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$. Therefore for some positive integer $N$ and $n > N$, $a_n<1$ and therefore $a_n^2<a_n$. Hence $\sum_{n>N} a_n^2<\sum_{n>N} a_n$. Since $\sum_{n>N} a_n$ converges, $\sum_{n>N} a_n^2$ converges.
 **Is this a valid argument?**

Comment: Looks good to me!

Comment: Yep. That's how I would do it as well. Good work!

Comment: Nitpick: I read "for some integer $N$ and $n>N$" as "$\exists N\exists n...$" whereas of course you mean $\exists N\forall n$, i.e. "there is some integer $N$ such that for all $n>N$..."

Comment: The final step hides details a bit. Because $s_M \equiv \sum_{ n=N}^M a_n^2$ is monotonically increasing in $M$ and bounded above by $\sum a_n$, it converges by the monotone convergence theorem.